# Firebase test lab displaying the message about exceeding quota

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

Hello Stackoverflow community!
I am trying to test with the Spark plan Robo test for **Firebase Test Lab**.
But it's showing that I already have exceeded quota for 5 devices, despite the fact, that I haven't tested anything yet. But I have 5 in sum for previous year. Can this be the issue? Thanks for the help
[image: 5 tests]
[image: Quota exceeded]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about quotas and billing should be send to Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Oh, okay. Thanks for the tip

Comment: But I think it's not for the billing, but rather bug, because it shows incorrect info  :)
But maybe you're right

Comment: I've looked up into the documentation. It says that at 12 PM it should reset __daily__ quota. But in my case, I have done tests in 2019, and haven't yet done any for 2020. Therefore, I think, this might be more a bug, rather than a billing issue :)

Comment: OK, contact Firebase support for bugs reports as well.

Comment: You can also reach out to the Firebase Test Lab team via the Firebase Community Slack. Post in the #test-lab channel.

Comment: @Maik thanks, I'll check it out, I haven't heard about that!

Answer (score 0):

Daily quota is per Firebase project, not per app. Are you sure a different app wasn't tested with this Spark project?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I only have this application enabled in Test Lab. Currently waiting for response from support